# how to print words inside a multi level char pointer array (c++)?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, pointers, vulkan

I have a
`const char** extentions`
of which is used with a call that returns an array into it.
`extentions= glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions(&extentionscount);`

im trying to print all the words in extentions.

my current code looks like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
            {
                for (int a = 0; a < 10; ++a)
                {

                    std::cout << extentions[i][a];
                }
                std::cout << "\n";
                
            }
```

which has a number of problems, im guessing the amount of words in this array by stopping the i loop at 3 and im guessing the word length of each word by stopping a at 10. (a workaround for i is putting extentionscount in there which should match the number of words, but then theres still the problem with the a loop)

how can i print all the words in this array?

many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've almost got it.

> a workaround for i is putting extentionscount in there which should match the number of words

That's no workaround, that's the solution ;)

Secondly: the strings in the array are null-terminated, so you don't need to iterate through them, just pass them to `cout`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < extensioncount; ++i)
{
    std::cout << extentions[i] << "\n";
}
```